# Which country's court interprets EULAs and Terms of Services online?

Tags: terms-of-service, eula

I'm thinking of writing a new kind of EULA for my software and Terms of Service for my art commissions and website. I'm not sure of which country a court interprets those legal documents. I live in Croatia, but the laws in Croatia about electronic goods and services are unknown to me and I have no money to afford a lawyer. I'm not sure if I should afford a lawyer in Croatia if maybe there's a united internet law of some kind where the EULAs and Terms of Services are interpretted.

Who interprets those? May I ask someone who's not in Croatia to write and interpret my EULAs and Terms of Services? Should I ask a free lawyer online? Of which country should that lawyer be?

Answer (score 2):

A court interprets things if you take someone to court. So the first step is to find a court that feels responsible. US courts feel responsible if the case is related to their area. For example, a court in Los Angeles would accept your court case if you lived in Los Angeles, or the person or company sued lived there. You'd need to check when a Croatian court would feel responsible.

The second step is to find out whether the person sued has to obey that court. If your court in Croatia orders someone in Los Angeles to pay you a million dollars, that person will likely just not pay. Unless they visit Croatia, there may be nothing you can do.

The court that looks at the EULA will be the court that you use.